# Using slippy-map tiles for large png data images

Tags: javascript, math, gis, tiles, analysis

I am using large PNGs (100 Megapixels) as data that I would like to be able to pan/zoom within the browser with javascript, and to convert the pixel data into raster data arrays.

We have a "dataset" library which manage arrays with width/height and several methods for image-to-data conversion, sampling, resizing, and convolution.  This data library already exists, but not adapted to tiles.
https://github.com/backspaces/agentscript/blob/master/extras/data.coffee

But the images we use are not GIS data, they're things like huge seismograph trace images, images with 24 traces of a pen on a rotating cylinder. And other large data sets we need to analyze, and would like the pan/zoom, level-of-detail features of slippy-maps.

Are there slippy-map (leaflet and others) approaches for non-GIS data?  I.e. I'd like to view/analyze data much the same as GIS does, but without the GIS semantics and assumptions.

I can build the 256x256 tiles using JavaScript, canvas, and dataurls.  But haven't found any existing project that uses generalized data images, not GIS, in slippy-maps.

What approach could I take to integrate non-GIS, large datasets into the slippy-map world?  Any projects out there for doing this?

Comment: I'm looking for something like this too, did you find a solution ?

Comment: No, alas.  Apparently we have to build it ourselves.  We've done a few prototypes, building our own set of slippy maps, both GIS and Data.  I wasn't involved so not sure how general it is at this point.

Comment: After much searching I found IIPImage server, that combined with leaflet and the leaflet iip plugin I get exactly what I need. Might work for you too.